# Show that $\int_{X}(\vert \alpha f_n - \alpha f + \beta g_n -\beta g\vert)^p d\mu \rightarrow 0 $ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$ for measurable f and g

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n,g_n, f ,g $ be measureable functions and $f_n\rightarrow f, g_n\rightarrow g$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

We also assume that:
$\int_{X}(\vert  f_n -  f \vert)^p d\mu \rightarrow 0$ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$ and the same holds for $\int\vert g_n-g\vert^pd\mu$

Now I want to show that $\int_{X}(\vert \alpha f_n - \alpha f + \beta g_n -\beta g\vert^p d\mu \rightarrow 0 $ for $ n \rightarrow \infty$.

So far I've been able to achieve that:

$lim\int_X\vert\alpha f_n-\alpha f+\beta g_n-\beta g\vert^pd\mu\leq lim\int_X(\vert\alpha\vert\vert f_n-f\vert+\vert\beta\vert\vert g_n-g\vert)^p d\mu$

Now if I could only make some argument that would allow me to move the limit inside the integral sign I feel like I could solve this, but I've no information that allows me to use either monotonous convergence or dominated convergence, from what I can tell. Any help here would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. Are you assuming that $\int |\alpha f_n -\alpha f|^{p} \to 0$?

Comment: Yes, I know that both $\int_X\vert f_n - f\vert^p \rightarrow 0$ and $\int_X\vert g_n-g\vert^p \rightarrow 0.$ This would imply the same holds when the functions are multiplied by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Hopefully this clears up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let $p \geq 1 $.

In any normed linear space $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ implies $x_n+y_n \to x+y$. $L^{p}$ is a normed linear space under the norm $\|f\|=(\
\int |f|^{p})^{1/p}$. Hence the result follows immediately. [It is a consequence of triangle in equality for this norm].

More explicitly the result follows from the inequality $(\int |\phi -\psi|^{p})^{1/p} \leq (\int |\phi |^{p})^{1/p}+(\int |\psi|^{p})^{1/p}$.

For $0<p<1$ the inequality you need is $(a+b)^{p} \leq a^{p}+b^{p}$ for all $a, b \geq 0$.

Comment: How are you concluding that $f_n,g_n,f,g$ are functions from $L^p$?

Comment: @EmilLenler I am not. I know that $\alpha (f_n-f)$ and $\beta (g_n-g)$ are in $L^{p}$ and this is enough.

Comment: Ah okay, I believe your comment uses Minkowski's Inequality, but does this not only hold for $p\geq 1$. I'd like to show that this holds for all $p>0$.

Comment: @EmilLenler I have added  a proof for $0<p<1$ also.